# How do you stop UITapGestureRecognizer from catching EVERY tap?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, button, conflict, uigesturerecognizer

Hello I have an opengl view and on that I have a tab bar. I'm using a tap recognizer to tap different 3d objects on screen. In the tab bar I have a button but it doesn't work because the tap recognizer catches these taps too. How do I stop this? I've already tried this:

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
  if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIBarButtonItem class]]) return FALSE;
  return TRUE;
}
```

I think I am somehow comparing wrong classess because when I debug it returns TRUE always.

Comment: your if-statement can never return false - a button is not a view... But you could check via a breakpoint in the debugger which type the view is you get on different tap positions.

Comment: Oh..I just noticed that `UIBarButtonItem` is not an `UIView` :) Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Or you can just do `[singleTap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO]`. Example:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [
    [UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
    initWithTarget: self
    action: @selector(yourSelector:)
];
[singleTap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer: singleTap];
```

Comment: Also available in the Interface Builder as _Canceled in View_. Great!

Comment: Only thing that worked. And like a charm, might I add! no messing with the rest of the code. thks!

Answer (score 28):

```
  if ([touch.view.superview isKindOfClass:[UIToolbar class]]) return FALSE;
```

This is how I got it to work. The superview is a UIToolbar, probably `UIBarButtonIttem` [is a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748512/ipad-uibarbuttonitem-has-an-undocumented-view-of-type-uitoolbartextbutton-huh) after all.

Comment: This worked where hit testing on the gesture recognizer's view failed. To be clear, I was working within a UITableView and the gesture's location was reported as `{0, contentOffset - someConstant}`. Checking the touch's view is a good solution. Thanks.