# Limit touch event to view

Tags: objective-c, ios, events, touch

I have a view with two swipe gesture recognizers. One left and one right.

On top of this view, i have another view with two other swipe gesture recognizers.

My problem is that any swipe i do on the second view gets sent to the parent view as well.

How do i prevent this? 
And, how do i prevent a touch event triggered in child view B from getting sent to parent view A?

thanks!

ps. sorry if this question was asked before.. i did try a bunch of stuff before asking, but nothing worked ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished with the `UIGestureRecognizer`'s `cancelsTouchesInView` property. Set this to `YES` on the subview's recognizers, and that should prevent the gestures from propagating to the parent view.

Comment: What if i don't have any gesture or touch recognizers on the child view? I just want to be able to push buttons and scroll without triggering the parents view recognizers.

Comment: Interesting. I would think that you should be able to override the `touchesBegan` method in the child view to handle that, but after a few minutes of playing around with that, I haven't found a working solution. This answer is likely what you need http://stackoverflow.com/a/5234804/144755

Answer (score 0):

I just finished a work-around that may help others that come across this thread.

The basic premise is to catch when a touch happens and remove gestures if the touch happened within a set of views. It then re-adds the gestures after the gesture recognizer handles the gestures.

```
@interface TouchIgnorer : UIView
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableSet * ignoreOnViews;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableSet * gesturesToIgnore;
@end
@implementation TouchIgnorer
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _ignoreOnViews = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
        _gesturesToIgnore = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
- (BOOL) pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint relativePt;
    for (UIView * view in _ignoreOnViews)
    {
        relativePt = [view convertPoint:point toView:view];
        if (!view.isHidden && CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, relativePt))
        {
            for (UIGestureRecognizer * gesture in _gesturesToIgnore)
            {
                [self removeGestureRecognizer:gesture];
            }
            [self performSelector:@selector(rebindGestures) withObject:self afterDelay:0];
            break;
        }
    }
    return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
}

- (void) rebindGestures
{
    for (UIGestureRecognizer * gesture in _gesturesToIgnore)
    {
        [self addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
    }
}
@end
```