# Pop view controller off stack without a navigation bar shown?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I've hidden the navigation bar so I can have a custom UIToolBar up there, but when I set the action property for the toolbar item to a method that pops it, it won't work, and I think it may be because I hid the navigation bar.

Here's my code:

```
[toolBarItems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Articles" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:@selector(backButtonTapped)]];
```

...

```
- (void)backButtonTapped {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: What do you mean by hid the navigation bar?  Check and see if you nav controller is nil

Comment: [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

Comment: And no, it's not nil.

Comment: hmm would probably need to see more code, the code you posted above is ok.  Try NSLogging your controller stack and make sure there is a view to pop to

Comment: Give me the answer of these : Is your method backButtonTapped calling ? Are there viewcontrollers count > 1 in you  self.navigationController.viewControllers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a UITapGestureRecognizer on the whole view that intercepted the tap on the UIBarButton. I solved it thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5887488/998117), which basically stopped the UITapGestureRecognizer from beginning unless it was outside of the UIToolBar.

Answer (score 3):

The target for your selector is nil when it should be self and you need to put the sender parameter in your action method!

```
[toolBarItems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Articles" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped:)]];

-(void) backButtonTapped: (id) sender {
   //code as before here
}
```

**edit** As @sulthan noted, the sender parameter is **not** needed! You can leave it out as you did before!

Comment: That did not change anything.

Comment: Please add a breakpoint to the popViewcontrollerAnimated: method and tell us if it is hit when you click the button

Comment: The `sender` parameter is optional.

Comment: @Sulthan can you give a reference o the docs? I didn't find that in the documentations an wasn't sure about that. Since I'm currently unable to compile th code myself, I thought that this was the problem.

Comment: @DougSmith be sure it has nothing to do with hiding the nav bar! Does the button you add ("Articles") appear in the toolbar? Is the backButtonTapped method inside your viewController on a method of another object?

Comment: @Mario [Target-Action in UIKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW44) There are three possible selector signatures.

Comment: Thanks @Sulthan you're right! Can't see what the problem is then

Comment: @Mario The code is okey with the exception of the `nil` target. A different error cannot be found without more code.

Comment: I answered with what was the problem. Thanks so much for the help, though, I'm sorry I didn't include more code but I didn't realize I had to.