# UIBarButtonItem not firing its action method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

In viewDidLoad:
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
NSMutableArray *toolBarItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[toolBarItems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Articles" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped)]];
[toolBarItems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Source" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil]];
[toolBarItems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil]];
[toolBarItems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Aa" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil]];
[toolBarItems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Rabbit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil]];
[toolBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
toolBar.items = toolBarItems;
[self.view addSubview:toolBar];
```

Method:

```
- (void)backButtonTapped {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I have a breakpoint on the call inside the method but it never gets called. Why is this method never getting called?

Comment: Why are you creating a `UIToolbar`? Why not use the toolbar that is already provided by the navigation controller? Where is your call to `self.toolbarItems = toolBarItems`?

Comment: Because I want different functionality than what the nav bar provides, and UIToolBars are the recommended way to go about what I'm doing. That call is further down.

Comment: But in what point do you add 'toolBar' you create to the navigation controller or to the view? Do you have a navigation controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a UITapGestureRecognizer on the whole view that intercepted the tap on the UIBarButton. I solved it thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5887488/998117), which basically stopped the UITapGestureRecognizer from beginning unless it was outside of the UIToolBar.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not complete and I dont know if you didn't implement it or just didn't wrote it here, so just to make sure, this should work:

```
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
NSMutableArray *toolBarItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[toolBarItems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Articles" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped)]];
toolBar.items = toolBarItems;
[self.view addSubview:toolBar];
```

Comment: I've attached the full code. That still doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. Its working fine.

```
 UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    UIBarButtonItem *infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"back"style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped)];
    [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:infoButton,nil]];
    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

Comment: I've attached the full code. That still doesn't work unfortunately.