# Multiple gestureRecognizers on views- one shouldn't pass touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

On parentClass(inheriting from UIView) i have:

```
[self addGestureRecognizer:_tapGesture]; // _tapGesture is UITapGestureRecognizer, with delegate on parentClass
```

On someClass:

```
[_myImageView addGestureRecognizer:_imageViewGestureRecognizer]; // _imageViewGestureRecognizer is UITapGestureRecognizer, with delegate on someClass
```

The problem is that when i tap on myImageView both gesture recognizers are firing. I want only _imageViewGestureRecognizer to work.

I've tried:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
   UIView *gestureView = recognizer.view;
   CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:gestureView];
   UIView *touchedView = [gestureView hitTest:point withEvent:nil];
   if ([touchedView isEqual:_imageViewGestureRecognizer]) {
     return NO;
   }

   return YES;
}
```

But it ofc doesn't take upon consideration gesture recognizer from super class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222998/uigesturerecognizer-blocks-subview-for-handling-touch-events

Comment: How about just disable that `_tapGesture` of the parent in your subclass?

Comment: @KhanhNguyen I can't do this, because when you tap anywhere else on superview (outside of _imageView) i need to get the touch.

Comment: @sathvik I wouldn't like to do it via method from 1st post, because parent view is from library- which i want to keep isolated from my app code.

Comment: Have your set cancelTouchesInView of the gesture to NO?

Comment: Oh I see your imageView is a subview...

Comment: @Rakesh yes, it doesn't help

Comment: No. What I meant is set cancelTouchesInView should be YES.

Comment: @Rakesh i've noticed your mistype ;) This doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this little test and it worked perfectly...

```
@implementation View

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped1)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];
    img.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    img.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    [self addSubview:img];

    UITapGestureRecognizer* tap2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped2)];
    [img addGestureRecognizer:tap2];

    return self;
}

-(void)tapped1 {
    NSLog(@"Tapped 1");
}

-(void)tapped2 {
    NSLog(@"Tapped 2");
}

@end
```

What you wanted was iOS's default behaviour. Once a subview has taken care of a touch, its superview won't receive the touch anymore. Did you set `userInteractionEnabled` on the imageView?

Comment: Hmm.. thanks for testing. I've got it set as userInteractionEnabled = YES, but in this case i have to look for problem elsewhere in code. Thanks once again, i'm marking this as answer ;) Now i'm wondering what can cause such a problem xD.

Comment: I've found solution, problem was from framework I've worked with. In case anyone occurs it: https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView/issues/68