# UITableViewCell subview does not receive touch

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

My reusable cell contains a view with all its informations (`UIImageView`, `UILabel`, etc.) with a frame of `0,0,320,63`, named `mainView`

I also have another subview, added programmatically, with a frame of `-160,0,160,63`, named `leftView`, contained in `mainView`.

I added a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to the cell, so when you swipe, I change the frame of mainView to `160,0,320,63`. It works perfectly.

I just have a problem, in `leftView`, I have some `UIImageView` with `userInteractionEnabled` set to `YES`, with a gesture recognizer on it. But this gesture recognizer is never fired, it still calls the `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

I looked at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222998/uigesturerecognizer-blocks-subview-for-handling-touch-events), but it does not help me.

Would somebody help me with that ?

Thank you !!

**EDIT : Here is my gesture recognizer instantiation**

```
// Selector is valid, I checked it out. _viewController too.
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[imageView setImage:someImage];
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[_leftView addSubview:imageView];
UITapGestureRecognizer * gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:_viewController action:selector];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:gr];
```

Comment: Post your gestureRecognizer initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

The problem was because the `leftView` frame was outside of the `mainView` frame (-160 in x).

To solve my problem, I changed `mainView` in storyboard, so that it also starts at -160. And instead of adding `leftView` at -160 in x, I add it at 0.

Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the gestureRecognizer's initialization, it could be a number of things that are the problem. Two main things to look into however:

1.) Have you set the `cancelsTouchesInView` flag? Normally this would be messing with your tableView touches, but you should look into it though.

2.) Have you verified the subview layout inside of storyboard? Is there something blocking part of your imageView?

-Also you've actually allocated the gestureRecognizer correct?

Comment: Thanks for your help. `cancelTouchesInView` isn't set. The subview isn't added from the storyboard, because I need to set it's frame programatically. I added my gesture recognizer initialization in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set table cell selectable to No? in this case your swipe gesture should still work, but table deligate method for cell selection shouldn't.

Comment: You mean by setting the userIteractionEnabled to NO on the cell ? If so, it doesn't work either.

Comment: No, I mean like this self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO; it will disable cell selection, and delegate method will not be called

Comment: Just tried, it didn't work. But I found a solution, I just answered myself. Thanks anyway.