# When I want to change the value in the `UISlider`, the scrollView scrolls left instead of the slider

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uislider, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have `UISlider` in `UICollectionView` scroll direction `horizontal`.

When I want to change the value in the `UISlider`, the scrollView scrolls left instead of the slider!!

I tried to add `UITapGestureRecognizer/UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to the slider.

It did not help.

Comment: Add some code of your.

Comment: It's common issue. Take a look at these answers and try them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222998/uigesturerecognizer-blocks-subview-for-handling-touch-events

Comment: Thanks, but It's not exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works! I added:

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

    if !self.userInteractionEnabled || self.hidden || self.alpha <= 0.01 {
        return nil
    }

    for subview:UIView in self.subviews{
        let convertedPoint:CGPoint = subview.convertPoint(point, fromView: self)
        if let hitTestView: UIView = subview.hitTest(convertedPoint, withEvent: event) {
            if viewRating.frame.contains(point){
                delegate!.stopScrollCollectionView(true)
            }else{
                delegate!.stopScrollCollectionView(false)
            }
            return hitTestView
        }
    }
    return self
}
```

Comment: What did you add this to?