# Does swipeGesture block the execution of touchesBegan()?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

my problem is that `touchesBegan()` is not called as I know it from other projects. Therefore there must be a difference somewhere to my other projects. Now I got the idea, that the following code prevents calling `touchesBegan()`:

In didMove()

```
tapRec.addTarget(self, action:#selector(GameScene.tappedView(_:) ))
    tapRec.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    tapRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec)
```

The function:

```
@objc func tappedView(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let point:CGPoint = sender.location(in: self.view)

    print("Single tap")

    print(point)

}
```

touchesBegan()

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {

        let locationUser = touch.location(in: self)

        if self.atPoint(locationUser) == background {
            print("background touch")
        }
    }
}
```

I come to the idea that the above function `tappedView()` is to blame for not executing `touchesBegan()`, since this function is called when the screen is touched instead of `touchesBegan()`.

Is there a way to use both `touchesBegan()` and `tappedView()` without them blocking each other?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: depends if you set the `cancelsTouchesInView` property of the gesture

Comment: I'm still not getting anywhere. What value must `cancelsTouchesInView` take for touchesBegan to work again?

Comment: I suggest you check out the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222998/uigesturerecognizer-blocks-subview-for-handling-touch-events